# SPSS - How to create a 'Totals' row (not a column)

Tags: spss

I have a dataset like this:

Program       Timely_Count           Total_Count

PROG1       51,761               53,356

PROG2   232,371     235,769

PROG3   100,756     110,859

PROG4   25,713      36,309

PROG5   17,985      18,995

PROG6   24,673      24,732

I want to create a "Total" row (not a column) so when I save this into Excel I will have a table that looks like this:

Program Timely_Count    Total_Count

PROG1   51,761      53,356

PROG2   232,371     235,769

PROG3   100,756     110,859

PROG4   25,713      36,309

PROG5   17,985      18,995

PROG6   24,673      24,732

TOTAL   453,259     480,020

I know I can use the AGGRAGATE function to add a TOTALS column, but that does not format the dataset the way I need for this report.

I also need this in syntax since it is run multiple times per day on multiple datasets. I have SPSS version 22. (If any of that helps.) –

Answer (score 1):

first you `aggregate`, then add the aggregated results back to your original table.

First let's recreate your sample data:

```
data list list/Program (a20) Timely_Count Total_Count (2f8).
begin data
PROG1 51,761 53,356
PROG2 232,371 235,769
PROG3 100,756 110,859
PROG4 25,713 36,309
PROG5 17,985 18,995
PROG6 24,673 24,732
end data.
```

Now run this:

```
dataset name OrigData.
dataset declare tot.
aggregate /out='tot'/break = /Timely_Count Total_Count=sum(Timely_Count Total_Count).
add files /file=*/file=tot.
recode program (""="TOTAL").
```

Comment: PERFECT!!!  Thank you so much!!  I knew there was a way but could not get it 100% there.  Works fine now!!